# MVVM: listview control on View is updated by Model properties but not by their wrapper properties in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a sample pure MVVM application. 
My problem is that if I bind Model property to ListView item on UI, it works well but when I try to bind wrapper of Model property [created in ViewModel] it does not work.

In my sample application, If I use Name & Location [Properties exposed in Model] properties in FamilyView.xaml\ListView control, it displays the items but if I use MemberName and MemberLocation [Properties exposed in ViewModel] it does not update the list.

What I understand about relation among layers in MVVM is that ViewModel separates View & Model. If so then we should use ViewModel properties to bind to View not the Model properties. Please suggest how to update my list by binding it to ViewModel properties.

My codes are as below:

FamilyView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_15thSep13.View.FamilyView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_15thSep13.ViewModel"
        Title="FamilyView" Height="283" Width="367">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:FamilyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Family.Name, FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,16,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Family.Location, FallbackValue=BindingFailed}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,57,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Command="{Binding AddDetailsCommand}" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,31,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Family}" Height="126" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,110,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" UseLayoutRounding="True">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}" Width="120"/>                    
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

FamilyModel.cs

```
namespace MVVM_15thSep13.Model
{
    public class FamilyModel:ObservableObject
    {
        private string m_Name;
        private string m_Location;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_Name; }
            set 
            {
                m_Name = value;
                if (m_Name != value)
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public string Location
        {
            get { return m_Location; }
            set
            {
                m_Location = value;
                if (m_Location != value)
                    OnPropertyChanged("Location");
            }
        }

        public FamilyModel()
        {
            m_Name = "Default Name";
            m_Location = "Default Location";
        }

        public FamilyModel(string name, string location)
        {
            m_Name = name;
            m_Location = location;
        }
    }
}
```

FamilyViewModel.cs

```
 namespace MVVM_15thSep13.ViewModel
{
    public class FamilyViewModel:ObservableObject
    {
        private FamilyModel m_Family;        
        private ObservableCollection<FamilyModel> m_FamilyCollection;
        private ICommand m_AddDetailsCommand;


        public FamilyViewModel()
        {           
            m_Family = new FamilyModel();
            m_FamilyCollection = new ObservableCollection<FamilyModel>();            
        }

        public FamilyModel Family
        {
            get { return m_Family; }
            set 
            {
                if (m_Family != value)
                {
                    m_Family = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Family");
                }
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<FamilyModel> FamilyCollection
        {
            get { return m_FamilyCollection; }
            set { m_FamilyCollection = value; }
        }       

        public ICommand AddDetailsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_AddDetailsCommand == null)
                    m_AddDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(param => AddFamilyDetails(), null);

                return m_AddDetailsCommand;
            }
        }

        public void AddFamilyDetails()
        {
            FamilyCollection.Add(Family);
            Family = new FamilyModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Other Helper Classes:

RelayCommand.cs

```
namespace MVVM_15thSep13.HelperClasses
{
    public class RelayCommand:ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> m_Execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> m_CanExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> exec) : this(exec, null) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> exec, Predicate<object> canExec)
        {
            if (exec == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("exec");

            m_Execute = exec;
            m_CanExecute = canExec;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
                return true;
            else
                return m_CanExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (m_CanExecute != null)
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                if (m_CanExecute != null)
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            m_Execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

ObservableObject.cs

```
namespace MVVM_15thSep13.HelperClasses
{
    public abstract class ObservableObject:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the inital value of MemberName and MemberLocation? Where do you raise MemberName and MemberLocation? Where does it react on changes in the model, so the view model knows that these properties are invalid aswell and need to be reraised?

Comment: @downhilefor: I don't think, I could understand your points clearly. But I have updated my View & ViewModel to bind with View Model properties. I also initialized property variables there. But it still does not work. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Forget my first comment. From what i see is, your DisplayMemberBinding is wrong, it says MemberName. But MemberName is not a Property on your FamilyModel. Are you aware that you aren't wrapping FamilyModel at all?

Answer (score 0):

You speak about view model wrapper properties, but you're not wrapping anything. Your view model is just doubling up the properties from the model. You have two choices; either implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface directly on your model classes and use instances of them in your view model (like you are now), or actually 'wrap' your model's properties in the view model:

```
private FamilyModel data;

public string Name
{
    get { return data.Name; }
    set { data.Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
}

public string Location
{
    get { return data.Location; }
    set { data.Location = value; OnPropertyChanged("Location"); }
}
```

UPDATE >>>

Sorry, I assumed that you could work the rest out by yourself. The instance of `FamilyModel` here is a private field. This is *never* data bound in the UI. Instead, you bind the 'wrapped' properties:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Location}" />
```

You would set the private `data` field in a constructor, or upon a particular `Button.Click`, etc.:

```
data = GetDataFromDatabaseOrWherever();
```

However, as you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface directly on your model classes, you don't *need* to do this... I just suggested this because you mentioned 'wrapper properties' in your question title.

Instead, you can just use your `Family` and `FamilyCollection` properties and get rid of the `MemberName` and `MemberLocation` properties unless they're for something specific. Using the `Family` property, you can bind to the UI like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Family.Name}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Family.Location}" />
```

My main point about your view model was that you *either* use wrapped properties, *or* you use your data types directly, but you *seem* to have both (unless `MemberName` and `MemberLocation` have nothing to do with your model.

If you are still having problems, then make sure that you've set the `DataContext` property of your view to an instance of your view model correctly.

UPDATE 2 >>>

Ok, I loaded up your code and found your problem.

For future reference, you can fix your own problems like this quite easily if you just look at the errors that you get in the `Output Window` in Visual Studio...it really is a WPF developer's best friend. There were two errors there:

> BindingExpression path error: 'MemberLocation' property not found on 'object' ''FamilyModel'
>   BindingExpression path error: 'MemberName' property not found on 'object' ''FamilyModel'

Searching your XAML for `MemberLocation` and `MemberName`, I could see your problem. You're trying to bind to these properties from the items in your `FamilyCollection` property... but this is an `ObservableCollection` of type `FamilyModel` and the `FamilyModel` class doesn't have any `MemberLocation` or `MemberName` properties in it. There's your error. To fix it, simply change your `GridView` to this:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="120"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}" Width="120"/>
</GridView>
```

Personally, I think that you should just get rid of your `MemberLocation` and `MemberName` properties... they are just confusing matters. Instead, you should just use your `Family` property like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Family.Name, FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Family.Location, FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" ... />
```

Then you could simplify your add method like this:

```
public void AddFamilyDetails()
{
    FamilyCollection.Add(Family);
    Family = new FamilyModel();
}
```

That would also enable you to do this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Family}" ... />
```

... which, if you haven't worked it out, will show the `Name` and `Location` values of the selected item in the `ListView` in the `TextBox`es. But of course, it's up to you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But here the problem is that 'FamilyModel'  is not binded to any control on UI, so it still does not update the listview.

Comment: @Sheridan From what i understand is, he is not wrapping the FamilyModel at all. He has one viewmodel which has a FamilyModel collection which is used directly.

Comment: Look again @dowhilefor, he has `MemberName` and `MemberLocation` properties in his view model... what are they for if not an attempt at wrapping his model properties? Also, look at his title... that's all I was going off.

Comment: @Sheridan: I tried to bind TextBox texts as FamilyName.Name & Family.Location, while ListView items as MemberName and MemberLocation.  MemberName getter/setter uses [m_Family.Name] while MemberLocation getter/setter use [m_Family.Location]. AddFamilyDetails() function [as in my above posted code] adds Family    data and Familycollection. DataContext is also set in View [can be seen as in my initial posted code]. But, now with these changes also  listview is not getting updated.

Comment: @Sheridan: I only wish to use properties on View from ViewModel, not directly from Model. Can I request you to copy paste my original code in VisualStudio application and use MemberName & MemberLocation for ListView binding instead of Name & Location, so that we may be on same page. I am trying things but it is not working out for me.

Comment: @Sheridan: Thanks Sher. I used your suggestions and am able to have items in my list. I have updated View and ViewModel code in my post above with the changes you suggested. But I have a query: Initially too I was able to have items in my list by using Name & Location properties. In your suggestion also, these two properties are bound with List items on UI. So,  I think we are disobeying MVVM here by allowing to bind Model properties to View or you think it is ok per MVVM rules?